# Build cmake on Heroku with Vulcan as a dependency for Taglib

Tags: heroku, cmake, taglib, buildpack, taglib-ruby

I'm trying to get [Taglib](http://taglib.github.com/) working on Heroku, so i can use the [taglib-ruby gem](http://robinst.github.com/taglib-ruby/). I've been fighting with Vulcan and a Custom Heroku Buildpack to get it working. One of Taglib's dependencies is cmake so i've been trying to get this working first.

There is an issue on Github which describes how cmake should be built, using Vulcan: [Issue #32](https://github.com/heroku/vulcan/issues/32), but i keep getting the same response from my build server:

```
---------------------------------------------
CMake 2.8.10.2, Copyright 2000-2012 Kitware, Inc.
Found GNU toolchain
C compiler on this system is: gcc 
C++ compiler on this system is: g++ 
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Cannot find appropriate Makefile processor on this system.
Please specify one using environment variable MAKE.
---------------------------------------------
Log of errors: /app/cmake-2.8.10.2/Bootstrap.cmk/cmake_bootstrap.log
---------------------------------------------
```

I think once cmake is working, building Taglib should be fairly straight forward.

I've followed Ryan Daigle's post on how Vulcan can be used build binary application dependancies too. I've established a remote shell to the Vulcan server and have run:

```
bin/make "5382f498-fd89-4c1a-9269-e05815294f40"
```

…where "5382f498-fd89-4c1a-9269-e05815294f40" is the id returned by Vulcan when the cmake build errors, but i receive the same error as above - no luck.

Can anyone offer any insight as to what i should be setting the MAKE environment variable as in order to get this working, please?

Comment: Is `make` installed on the machine? If yes, I'd try setting e.g. MAKE=/usr/bin/make when building CMake.

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`bin/vulcan-make "5382f498-fd89-4c1a-9269-e05815294f40"`